# UibModal - open on pending mode without promise

Tags: modal-dialog, angular-ui-bootstrap

is it possible to open UIBMODAL when there are request on pending mode?

for now its stuck until the connection is restored and all pendind request works like queue and then the popup appear

i want that the popup will work without promise or any request - for error cases

modal code:

```
  var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
           animation: false,
           templateUrl: 'modal.html',
           controller: function($scope, $uibModalInstance) {

             $scope.closeModal = function() {
               $uibModalInstance.close();
             };
           },
           scope: $scope,
           size: 'lg'
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all browsers limit you on how many pending HTTP requests you can have at any given time (about 6 or so), so if your modal has to resolve some data from a service/server, and you have requests running you will have to wait for them to finish.

Your options are

1. Run these requests before the view is rendered, you can do so when you resolve (`.resolve`) into your route/state
2. First load the modal, and then load the data on a service inside the modal's controller.

Also by using `templateUrl` you are sending a http request for an html file on the server side, usually these templates will be cached but for simpler modals you can use the inline `template` instead.